# CASE WHEN - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following (which I know is syntactically incorrect, maybe even bearing on ridiculous):

```
and lp.lease_current_stop_date
    case when @lease_expiry_period = 01
    then
        between dateadd(MONTH, +1,
                       getdate())
    else
        between dateadd(MONTH, +2,
                       getdate())
```

I'm just wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this? What I'm trying to do with the above is:

*When @lease_expiry_period is equal to 01 then show all leases expiring up to a month from now. When @lease_expiry_period is equal to 02 then show all leases expiring up to two months from now.*

**Performance note**

Worth noting that I didn't truncate the date in my example for simplicity also. As this is using month getdate() should be:

```
Dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,getdate()))
```

For best performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
AND lp.lease_current_stop_date BETWEEN getdate() AND dateadd(MONTH, @lease_expiry_period, getdate())
```

Comment: +1. nice one.  I used a computed case, but haven't posted as your is neater.

Comment: Worth noting that I didn't truncate the date in my example for simplicity also. As this is using month getdate() should also have Dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,getdate())) for best performance

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the spec e.g. when `@lease_expiry_period = 03` it will show leases expiring up to three months from now and I don't see that in the spec.

Comment: If you want to clamp, you can do `MIN(@lease_expiry_period, 2)` instead of just `@lease_expiry_period`, but I think @Codingo just didn't spell out the generalization he was making.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this last point of yours? Unsure what you mean by: "if you want to clamp"?

Comment: If you want a limit to the number of months ahead. E.g. `@lease_expiry_period = 05`, but only look at most two months ahead. @onedaywhen is pointing out that there's multiple ways to understand your question, from very literal (like his solution), to following the general pattern (like mine).

Comment: The way they quoted the two rules makes it look like then were quoting a document written by someone else, so maybe the OP here doesn't even know the correct interpretation. Is it safe to assume a) a progression at all and b) specifically arithmetic progression based on the two rules? My experience tells me to err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following

```
    select * 
    from [table] lp
    where  lp.lease_current_stop_date= (
    select case 
        when @lease_expiry_period = 01
        then
            dateadd(MONTH, +1, getdate())
        else
            dateadd(MONTH, +2,getdate())
        end)
```

Comment: Francis's answer is actually much more succinct

Comment: I agree and going with Fancis's answer but greatly appreciate the time you put into this. It also helps me to understand case/when a lot better so thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

```
...
AND 'T' = CASE WHEN @lease_expiry_period IN (01, 02) THEN
             CASE WHEN lp.lease_current_stop_date 
                         BETWEEN getdate() 
                         AND dateadd(MONTH, @lease_expiry_period, getdate())                            
                  THEN 'T'
             END
          END
AND ...
```